# How to set attributes on multiple same-tag elements in JointJS/Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, css-selectors, jointjs

In [JointJS](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.1/joint.html) an element has SVG template markup, and you can dynamically alter what is output by setting attributes on an element.  I cannot discover a way of selecting a particular tag in the markup where there are multiple occurrences of the same tag.

The JointJS documentation includes:

> Another important property is `attrs` which is an object with keys
>   representing selectors that match subelements and values which are SVG
>   attributes that will be set on the subelements.

and

> [properties] can be accessed or set directly using the regular
>   Backbone `set()`/`get()` methods

So I'm not sure whether my question concerns JointJS only or applies to Backbone or other technologies more generally.

**My Problem**:

If I have markup:

```
<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect/></g><image/><text/></g>
```

I can address the `image` element via:

```
element.attr('image', { style: "display: none;" });
```

However, I want *two* image elements:

```
<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect/></g><image/><image/><text/></g>
```

Now `.attr('image')` accesses the first one.  I cannot find a syntax to access the second one.  I have tried things like:

```
<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect/></g><image id="img1"/><image id="img2"/><text/></g>
```

but `element.attr('#img2')` does not seem to work.  Similarly for:

```
<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect/></g><image class="img1"/><image class="img2"/><text/></g>
```

but `element.attr('.img2')` does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this behaviour is purely in JointJS code, not Backbone.  Although the documentation talks about using CSS selectors to refer to elements, I believe it is some internal, cut-down syntax that has to be used.

It seems you cannot use anything like `image .class` as a selector, as you could in CSS.  It accepts either a tag name or a class name but not both.  So I have given each of the two `<image>`s its own unique class name, and am able to use `.class1` & `.class2` to address each element.